# Why do mushrooms grow in rings (sometimes called "Fairy Rings")?

Tags: mycology

Mushrooms disperse their spore in all direction. Then why is there a formation of fairy rings? **Why do they grow in one shape and not randomly?**

Comment: Welcome! I think this is an excellent question! :)

Comment: The mushrooms require a lot of nitrogen, more than grass, and they deplete the nitrogen enough that the grass withers, so they grow outwards. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_ring#Necrotic_or_rapid_growth_zones

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When spores germinate, they do not generate mushrooms directly, but haploid [mycelium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycelium) starts to grow. Only when the mycelium from spores with the other mating type is met, cells fuse and generate diploid mycelium, from which mushrooms can grow.

[image: basidiocycle]

Fairy rings are caused by a radial outgrowth pattern of the diploid mycelium, followed by resource depletion in the oldest part (middle).

[image]

[This](http://www.cpbr.gov.au/fungi/mycelium.html) page seems to have good additional information about hyphal growth.